# Combining the required fields from two different models

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am implementing django application where I have two models file and filepage in which filepage model has a foreign key file.

currently my view looks like this:

```
Container     P        Bucket_type

f1      p1        doc1
f1      p2        doc2
f1      p3        doc3
f2      p4        doc4
f2      p5        doc5
```

I want to convert it into:

```
Container      P           Bucket_type

f1    p1,p2,p3     doc1,doc2,doc3
f2    p4,p5        doc4,doc5
```

the container name is field in my container model and student and bucket type are in bucket model.

Updated:

```
class Containers(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class Bucket(models.Model):
    file = models.ForeignKey(Container, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='buckets')
    bucket_number = models.IntegerField()
    p = models.ForeignKey(P, null=True, blank=True)
    bucket_type = models.ForeignKey(D, null=True, blank=True)
```

currently I am trying to write a function which combines this records but it is taking time to make that list of combinations as I have bulk of records in my database.

Is there any way to create this data using Django's third party packages or any other solution?

Comment: It would be better if you could show us the actual django model.

Comment: Consider using ManyToMany Relation instead of ForeignKey.

Comment: Do You want combine values of Your fields? You want concatenate values of p1, p2, p3 in one field and p4, p5 in other?

Comment: I want to combine values of p1, p2, p3 in one field and p4, p5 in other field  by comma separation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Bucket` model should look like this

```
class Bucket(models.Model):
    file = models.ForeignKey(Container, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='buckets')
    bucket_number = models.IntegerField()
    student = models.ManyToManyField(Student, null=True, blank=True)
    bucket_type = models.ManyToManyField(BucketType, null=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can Try to create Charfield or Charfields in YouModel:

```
patient1 = FilePage.objects.order_by('patient')[0]  # --  [0] or other variant
document1 = FilePage.objects.order_by('document_type')[0]  # --  [0] or other variant
YouModel.objects.order_by('charfield').update(charfield=patient1) # Something like this construction.
```

For Most convenient construction i need to Ask You "What You Want?", and comment You post. But i can`t do this because i havn`t 50 REPUTATION.